# Sequence queue limit comparison test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

\mathrm 
If I given two sequences :$a_n$ and $b_n$ both positive and it given to me too that:
$a_{n+1}/a_n$ <= $b_{n+1}/b_n$
and I need to prove if  $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges than converges $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ too.

I thought that because I gived without general restrictions that because $b_{n+1}/b_n$ is bigger than 
$a_{n+1}/a_n$, that means that from $n0$ from $\mathbb{N}$ our sequence $a_n$ will be monotonic descending sequence as $b_n$ too from $n1$ from  $\mathbb{N}$ and ill take the $max(n1,n0)= n_d$.
Because this infinite sequence an in the organ number $n_k$ $a_n$ will be smaller than $b_n$ and both sequences will converge to 0 that means $a_n$ <= $b_n$
If I assuming that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges thats means $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges too because the sentence of column comparison test.

Is my way of thinking is correct ? I just doodled to you my way of thinking to see if it's correct .
Sorry about my english and my grammer mistakes English isn't my mother language.
'
Jonathan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

By induction for $n > p$

$$\frac{a_n}{a_p} \le \frac{b_n}{b_p}$$ and therefore

$$\frac{1}{a_p} \sum_{k=p}^n a_k\le \frac{1}{b_p} \sum_{k=p}^n b_k$$

then use Cauchy criteria.

However coming back to your question regarding monotonicity, neither $\{b_n\}$ nor $\{a_n\}$ are supposed to be monotonic. So you can't suppose that.

Comment: how can i conclude that the transition from the induction assuming for n>p is correct to the sum of them too

Comment: Fix $p$ and vary $n$.